# MvvmCross ICommand for elements inside ListView item

Tags: c#, android, mobile, xamarin, mvvmcross

MvvmCross provides a beautiful way for handling user commands directly in ViewModel (which can be written only once in Core library).

I can easily use the ICommand pattern for the whole list item, for example:

```
local:MvxBind="ItemsSource Contacts; ItemClick ShowContactCommand"
local:MvxItemTemplate="@layout/item_contacts"
```

But what if I have a button in my item_contacts item layout? How can I bind the click on this button to a particular property in my ViewModel? (if possible, without writing any platform-specific code in the View class).

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15924660/mvvmcross-bindings-for-android/15925195#15925195
and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17851371/binding-to-parent-and-grandparent

Comment: Thank you very much, was quite obvious actually! Works like a charm :)