# MvvmCross : DataBind a parent property on Android

Tags: c#, android, binding, datatemplate, mvvmcross

I would find an equivalent of Path and ElementName properties (Silverlight XAML) on Android AXML :
Android using (color) converters, as Windows Phone / Windows 8...

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="Items">
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Rectangle Fill="{Binding Path=Family.Couleur, ElementName=LayoutRoot, Converter={StaticResource NativeColor}}"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

The code of my parent control :

```
<Mvx.MvxGridView ... local:MvxBind="ItemsSource Items"
    local:MvxItemTemplate="@layout/locationtileview" />
```

I want to customize the background of each element with a specified property in the context of my MvxLinearLayout.
My ItemTemplate :

```
<Mvx.MvxLinearLayout ... local:MvxBind="{'background':{'Path':'Family.Couleur'}, {'Converter':{'Path':'NativeColor'}}">
    ...
</Mvx.MvxLinearLayout>
```

But, when I debug this, I've this stacktrace for each item :

```
MvxBind:Error:113.02 Problem parsing binding MvxException: PropertyName must start with letter - position 0 in {'Background':{'Path':'FamilyDTO.Couleur'}, 'Converter':{'Path':'NativeColor'}} - char {
02-26 15:22:28.859 I/mono-stdout( 1346): MvxBind:Error:113.02 Problem parsing binding MvxException: PropertyName must start with letter - position 0 in {'Background':{'Path':'FamilyDTO.Couleur'}, 'Converter':{'Path':'NativeColor'}} - char {
02-26 15:22:28.859 I/mono-stdout( 1346):      at Cirrious.CrossCore.Parse.MvxParser.ReadValidCSharpName () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
      at Cirrious.CrossCore.Parse.MvxParser.ReadValidCSharpName () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at Cirrious.MvvmCross.Binding.Parse.Binding.MvxBindingParser.ReadTargetPropertyName () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
02-26 15:22:28.859 I/mono-stdout( 1346):   at Cirrious.MvvmCross.Binding.Parse.Binding.MvxBindingParser.ReadTargetPropertyName () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
02-26 15:22:28.859 I/mono-stdout( 1346):   at Cirrious.MvvmCross.Binding.Parse.Binding.MvxBindingParser.ParseTargetPropertyNameAndDescription () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at Cirrious.MvvmCross.Binding.Parse.Binding.MvxBindingParser.ParseTargetPropertyNameAndDescription () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 

  at Cirrious.MvvmCross.Binding.Parse.Binding.MvxBindingParser.TryParseBindingSpecification (System.String text, Cirrious.MvvmCross.Binding.Parse.Binding.MvxSerializableBindingSpecification& requestedBindings) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
```

Comment: see also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21591127/mvvmcross-icommand-for-elements-inside-listview-item and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15924660/mvvmcross-bindings-for-android/15925195#15925195 and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17851371/binding-to-parent-and-grandparent

Comment: but I want to use MvvmCross Converters

Comment: Which you can do if you use a wrapper object like in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14208203/mvvmcross-android-alternative-to-relativesource-binding-for-button-command

Comment: I don't understand... 
I've : local:MvxBind="{'Background':{'Path':'FamilyDTO.Couleur'}, 'Converter':{'Path':'NativeColor'}}" and do not work...